# Evaluate the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, physics, hyperbolic-functions

Show that $$\int\limits_{0}^{b}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=\sinh^{-1}\frac{b}{a}$$

However, when I use Maple or WolframAlpha to calculate the left integration, both gave me $-\frac{\ln(a^2)}{2}+\ln(b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2})$, which seems not agree with the result on the right.

[This integration is from the book [Introduction to Superconductivity
Second Edition By Michael Tinkham](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Introduction_to_Superconductivity/JOQoAwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0) `Page 56`]

A snapshot of the textbook

> [image].

The $\Delta$ is independent of $\xi$.

This is from the famous BCS theory and I think it should be correct. Also, I have checked another book, which shows the same result ($\sinh^{-1}\frac{b}{a}$).

Comment: What happens if you apply sinh to the wolfram alpha result?

Comment: Have you ever tried to find $\sinh^{-1}$ by hand? $\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=a$, let $t=e^x$, then $t^2-1=2at$, $t=a\pm\sqrt{a^2+1}$ so $x=\ln\left(a\pm\sqrt{a^2+1}\right)=\sinh^{-1}(a)$. Looks familiar?) @ying

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll check by hand next time for a similar situation. Thank you~~ @AlexeyBurdin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a link between $ sinh^{-1} $ and $ \ln $ via:

$$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}=y$$
$$x=\sinh^{-1}(y)$$
By solving for $ e^x $, the equation
$$e^{2x}-2ye^x-1=0$$
we find
$$e^x=y+\sqrt{y^2+1}$$
and then
$$x=\sinh^{-1}(y)=\ln(y+\sqrt{y^2+1})$$

So if $a>0$,
$$\sinh^{-1}\Bigl(\frac ba\Bigr)=\ln\Bigl(\frac ba+\sqrt{\frac{b^2}{a^2}+1}\Bigr)$$

$$=\ln\Bigl(\frac{b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a}\Bigr)$$
$$=\ln(b+\sqrt{b^2+a^2})-\ln(a)$$

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

They are indeed equivalent expressions.
$${\text{sinh}}^{-1}(x)=\ln{\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\right)}$$
For your problem, $x=\frac{b}{a}$:
$${\text{sinh}}^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)=\ln{\left(\frac{b}{a}+\sqrt{{\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)}^2+1}\right)}$$
$$=\ln{\left(b+\sqrt{b^2+a^2}\right)}-\ln{a}$$
$${\text{sinh}}^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)=-\frac{\ln{(a^2)}}{2}+\ln{\left(b+\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\right)}$$

Comment: Missed the ln().

Comment: Many thanks!! I got it.